# alias for expressions in hql queries

Tags: sql, hql

my Hibernate version is 3.2.6.ga

Googling around reveals many people are having the same problems with
Hibernate HQL not handling aliases very well.  Apparently HQL only lets
you alias a column that exists in a table. Also, HQL generates its own
aliases for all columns in the query and these have the form
    col_x_y_
but how these are generated I don't know.

For my case I want to add two derived columns into a third derived column.
Trivial in native SQL, surprisingly difficult in HQL.

My contrived, simplified example:

```
sqlcmd = " SELECT  aa.course.code, " +
         "        (CASE WHEN aa.gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),  " +
         "        (CASE WHEN aa.gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),  " +
         "        ( col_0_1_ + col_0_2_ ) " +
         "        FROM Student AS aa ";
```

How can I add the 2nd and 3rd columns together to form a 4th column in HQL?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I hope you've found your answer by now, but if you haven't, I've learned a few new things about how nhibernate handles column alias's. So here's my answer for you.

```
sqlcmd = " SELECT  aa.course.code, " +
         "        (CASE WHEN aa.gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),  " +
         "        (CASE WHEN aa.gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),  " +
         "        ( col_0_1_ + col_0_2_ ) " +
         "        ( col_0_2_ + col_0_3_ ) " + 
         "        FROM Student AS aa ";
```

you really answered this yourself by noting that NH generates it's own column alias names. My research has told me that this only is in ORDER BY statements and it's a bug they're working on. So honestly I think you're okay with using your own column alias's here

```
sqlcmd = " SELECT  aa.course.code, " +
         "        (CASE WHEN aa.gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) myCol1,  " +
         "        (CASE WHEN aa.gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) myCol2,  " +
         "        ( myCol1 + myCol2 ) myCol3 " +
         "        ( myCol2 + myCol3 ) myCol4 " + 
         "        FROM Student AS aa ";
```

but in either case you can keep using the alias's that NH throws out at you and it will be in the form of col_x_y_

hope this helps, good luck